# Bootstrap Modal input focus doesn't pull up the keyboard on an iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I'm trying to focus on an input field in a bootstrap modal using this code:

```
   $('#Modal9').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#multiplyInput").focus();
        });
```

It does focus on my input that has the id=multiplyInput inside the modal but it doesn't pull up the keyboard using safari in an iPad. that happens only if the input field is inside a Modal otherwise it works fine.

any suggestions ?
thank you

Comment: You can try to trigger a click on the input after you focus it. With jQuery: `$("#multiplyInput").focus().trigger('click');` or with vanilla JS: `$("#multiplyInput").focus().click();`. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: haven't thought about that. it's a good idea but unfortunately it didn't work